# Redirection from the php file

Tags: php

I'm looking for a little help from someone who knows PHP,
in short, it looks like this:
I once made a website for a customer with products on the Jomla CMS system, and the product was located, for example, at:

www.mysite.pl/index.php/productall/product1

www.mysite.pl/index.php/productall/product2
e.t.c...

currently his site has been changed and is in the classic html5 / css / js without any CMS, but in the same old directory
and the product is on:
www.mysite.pl/product1.html

The client created QR codes for himself, but to the old page and printed on each product
and now I would like to create an index.php file, which will redirect the traffic depending on the call in the browser, because now as the QR code is being scanned it jumped out because there is no such adreas as before.

For now, I created an index.php file that redirects to

www.mysite.pl/allproduct.hml

where is the list of all products but I would prefer it to be as before
that is, each QRcode was redirected to the chosen product.
Can you do it somehow? PLEASE HELP

now i have this code in index.php

Comment: You need to do 301 redirects using htaccess ie `Redirect 301 
 /index.php/productall/product1 www.mysite.pl/product1.html` for each product

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with PHP, You could try adding redirect commands within the htaccess file? (*if you can still use one?*) The "**.htaccess**" file should be located in the site root.
ie: **/public_html/.htaccess**

within this file you can create redirects from the old address to the new one.

```
Redirect 301 /oldProductLink1.html http://www.example.com/NewProductPage1.html
Redirect 301 /oldProductLink2.html http://www.example.com/NewProductPage2.html
```

:)

Comment: i still have this: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: 0


i still have this:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I removed this my test index.php file and created .htaccess in the root directory with yours codes

Comment: That error message sounds like a windows server type error, I would double check your hosting setup, you may need to use a web.config file if its a windows based server & not Linux...

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy solution you must create a .htacess file and place on your root folder then redirect all the old urls to new url for each product

```
Redirect 301  /index.php/productall/product1 www.mysite.pl/product1.html
Redirect 301 /index.php/productall/product1 www.mysite.pl/product2.html
Redirect 301 /index.php/productall/product1 www.mysite.pl/product3.html
Redirect 301 /index.php/productall/product1 www.mysite.pl/product4.html
```

Comment: just beat me to it :)

Comment: i try it but
i still have this:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I removed this my test index.php file and created .htaccess in the root directory with yours codes

Answer (score 0):

If the question is only about PHP and there is no way to use web server URL rewriting or redirect, then you should create files like :

`/index.php/productall/product1
/index.php/productall/product2`

Where index.php would be a directory. Each file should contain something like :

`header('location: /product1.html');
exit();`

Where the product number should be set according to file name.

Comment: index.php can't be a directory on server

Comment: So in a way or another you will have to deal with redirects or URL rewriting as other people suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i still have this:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I removed this my test index.php file and created .htaccess in the root directory with yours codes